# Audio not working with Chromium Web Browser but works with VLC

Tags: audio, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with raspbian buster desktop installed which I am using since 1 year to consume media over internet. I am using bluetooth to connect with the speakers and everything was working perfect until yesterday I did software update and the chromium web browser stopped giving audio output. However, I would play mp3 audio or video files using VLC and the audio worked perfectly.

After check with all the settings, I removed the SD card and reflashed it with the latest raspberry pi buster full desktop image that was downloaded fresh. After install, I let it do software updates and the Chromium web browser audio is still broken. And I am able to play audio and video with VLC.

Is there something with the current update that is breaking the chromium web browser? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: So, I just re-flashed the SD card again with latest desktop image and made sure I dont install any software updates. And audio is working well with chromium. It seems the update is breaking the audio for chromium only. 

Never going to update now! Very sad outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear that you solved it with a fresh install of the OS. Yeah, I've had similar issues where flashing the SD card with the latest OS was the solution as well. This is why I use raspiBackup to make sure I'm always backed up (and I keep an extra SD card or two laying around just for these situations).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Raspberry Pi 4 and fixed it by updating Chromium to the latest version. Raspbian 10 comes with version 78. After running the update I was at version 88. Audio worked fine through the browser after the update.

I ran the command:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser --yes
```