# Bluetooth Audio not working with Chromium

Tags: audio, bluetooth, chromium

I am having a problem using Chromium with bluetooth.  I have a new Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian Buster. Using VLC, or aplay at command prompt, I can hear audio through bluetooth headset. However, I cannot hear audio from Chromium. I am new to Raspberry Pi and this OS. I have worked with Windows in app development for many years. I did make some changes so that I could properly stream video from my Netflix account using the Chromium browser. The changes came from a developer named [Ventz](https://blog.vpetkov.net/).  Those changes installed a selection under the Internet menu called Chromium (Media Edition). This worked great but I was previously using analog audio output. Now I want to use a bluetooth headset but it does not work with Chromium.  My problem may be the same as [This Problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118344/audio-not-working-with-chromium-web-browser-but-works-with-vlc) but this forum seems to want only posts that are answers and not posts with additional information to the same problem. So I could not add my information to that post.

Comment: Have you upgraded to the the [December 2020 Raspbian release](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-raspberry-pi-os-release-december-2020/)? I am using a fresh flash of that and bluetooth speakers/headsets are working fine on my pi4b.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be a conflict between the software you're running along with the native bluetooth libraries (there are a bunch of them, it is easy to run into issues like this when making customizations like you're doing). I would try to isolate where the issue is emanating from to begin with. If you have another SD card on hand, I would incrementally test the functionality of the BT as you do these changes. That way you can easily determine where the fail point is. Then you can reconfigure your current SD card according to where it is. . . I'd tread carefully though. I've fallen into the Bluetooth black hole here myself and ended up simply abandoning some projects and going back to default BT settings for ease of simplicity.

Good luck!